node native c++ code in electron unexpected character
This is my folder structure:
└── my-electron-project/
├── lib/
│   └── addon/
│       ├── build/
│       │   └── Release/
│       │       └── addon.node
│       ├── addon.cc
│       ├── binding.gyp
│       ├── index.js
│       └── package.json
├── main/
│   ├── main.js
│   └── preload.js
├── src/
│   └── app/
│       ├── page.tsx
│       └── api/
│           └── hello/
│               └── route.ts
└── package.json

The issue in short:
I'm getting the error Module parse failed: Unexpected character '�' (1:2)
for my addon:
addon.cc
#include <node_api.h>
#include <assert.h>

napi_value Addon(napi_env env, napi_callback_info info) {
    napi_status status;
        napi_value args[1];
        
        size_t argc = 1;
        status = napi_get_cb_info(env, info, &argc, args, NULL, NULL);
        if(status != napi_ok) {
            return nullptr;
        }
        

        char buf[128];
        size_t buf_size = 128;
        size_t copied_size = 128;
        status = napi_get_value_string_utf8(env, args[0], buf, 128 + 1, &copied_size);
        if(status != napi_ok) {
            return nullptr;
        }



        napi_value output;
        status = napi_create_string_utf8(env, buf, copied_size, &output);
        if(status != napi_ok) {
            return nullptr;
        }

        return output;
}

#define DECLARE_NAPI_METHOD(name, func) {name, 0, func, 0, 0, 0, napi_default, 0}

napi_value Init(napi_env env, napi_value exports) {
    napi_status status;
    napi_property_descriptor desc = DECLARE_NAPI_METHOD("Addon", Addon);
    status = napi_define_properties(env, exports, 1, &desc);
    assert(status == napi_ok);
    return exports;
}

NAPI_MODULE(NODE_GYP_MODULE_NAME, Init);

binding.gyp:
{
    "targets": [
        {
            "target_name":"addon",
            "sources": [
                "addon.cc"
            ]
        }
    ]
}

index.js:
const addonNative = require('bindings')('Addon')

console.log(addonNative.Addon("test"))

Commands (all in /lib/addon)
npm configure
nmp build
node index.js > gives "test" which is as expected
Also, I run:
node-gyp rebuild --target=20.12.2 --arch=x64 --dist-url=https://atom.io/download/atom-shell
NextJS / Electron:
page.tsx:
"use client";
import { useEffect, useState } from "react";

export default function Home() {
  const [message, setMessage] = useState<string>("default");

  const getData = async () =>
    fetch("/api/hello")
      .then(function (response) {
        return response.text();
      })
      .then(function (data_raw) {
        const data = JSON.parse(data_raw);
        setMessage(data.message);
      });

  useEffect(() => {
    getData();
  }, []);

  return (
    <main className="p-24">
      {message}
    </main>
  );
}

api/hello/route.ts:
import { NextResponse } from "next/server";

const addon = require('/lib/addon/addon.node')

export async function GET() {
  console.log(process.version)
  try {
    const result = addon.Addon("test");
    return NextResponse.json({
      message: result
    });
  } catch(error) {
    return NextResponse.json({
      message: error.message
    });
  }
  
}

Commands (in /):
npm run dev
This gives me:
electron-nextjs-project@0.1.0 dev
> concurrently -n "NEXT,ELECTRON" -c "yellow,blue" --kill-others "next dev" "electron ."

[ELECTRON] 
[ELECTRON] [9564:0716/112012.339:ERROR:web_contents_preferences.cc(240)] preload script must have absolute path.
[NEXT]   ▲ Next.js 14.2.4
[NEXT]   - Local:        http://localhost:3000
[NEXT]
[NEXT]  ✓ Starting...
[NEXT]  ✓ Ready in 17.4s
[NEXT]  ○ Compiling / ...
[NEXT]  ✓ Compiled / in 966ms (490 modules)
[NEXT]  GET / 200 in 1166ms
[NEXT]  ✓ Compiled in 151ms (239 modules)
[NEXT]  ⨯ ./lib/addon/addon.node
[NEXT] Module parse failed: Unexpected character '�' (1:2)
[NEXT] You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type, currently no loaders are configured to process this file. See https://webpack.js.org/concepts#loaders
[NEXT] (Source code omitted for this binary file)
[NEXT]
[NEXT] Import trace for requested module:
[NEXT] ./lib/addon/addon.node
[NEXT] ./src/app/api/hello/route.ts
[NEXT]  ⨯ ./lib/addon/addon.node
[NEXT] Module parse failed: Unexpected character '�' (1:2)
[NEXT] You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type, currently no loaders are configured to process this file. See https://webpack.js.org/concepts#loaders
[NEXT] (Source code omitted for this binary file)
[NEXT]
[NEXT] Import trace for requested module:
[NEXT] ./lib/addon/addon.node
[NEXT] ./src/app/api/hello/route.ts
[NEXT]  ○ Compiling /_not-found ...
[NEXT]  ⨯ ./lib/addon/addon.node
[NEXT] Module parse failed: Unexpected character '�' (1:2)
[NEXT] You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type, currently no loaders are configured to process this file. See https://webpack.js.org/concepts#loaders
[NEXT] (Source code omitted for this binary file)
[NEXT]
[NEXT] Import trace for requested module:
[NEXT] ./lib/addon/addon.node
[NEXT] ./src/app/api/hello/route.ts
[NEXT]  ⨯ ./lib/addon/addon.node
[NEXT] Module parse failed: Unexpected character '�' (1:2)
[NEXT] You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type, currently no loaders are configured to process this file. See https://webpack.js.org/concepts#loaders
[NEXT] (Source code omitted for this binary file)
[NEXT]
[NEXT] Import trace for requested module:
[NEXT] ./lib/addon/addon.node
[NEXT] ./src/app/api/hello/route.ts
[NEXT]  GET /api/hello 500 in 2434ms
[NEXT]  GET /api/hello 500 in 21ms
[NEXT]  GET / 500 in 9ms

Any idea how I can solve these errors and just get the expected "test" line into my nextresponse message?

"Any idea how I can solve these errors" - Find out where that weird character is - in a file name or in file contents - and remove or change it.

The character is related to the line const addon = require('/lib/addon/addon.node'). When it is not there, there is no error. Seems odd when the same is working on node index.js. So I think there is more going on than you suggest.

I'd guess a bom marker in a file somewhere
